# modelsummary: goodness-of-fit disappeares when the table shape is changed

Tags: r, modelsummary, goodness-of-fit

When I use the R package modelsummary, I want the models to be vertically arragnged and the statistics to be horizontally. The default formula for *shape* is *term + statistic ~ model*, and the normal table is complete

```
mod_custom <- lm(hp ~ mpg + drat, mtcars)
modelsummary(mod_custom)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKGkq.png). However, when I change the shape to be *model ~term + statistic*, all the goodness-of-fit disappears:

```
modelsummary(mod_custom,
             shape=model ~term + statistic,
             )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPBiS.png)

I have tried to set the parameter

```
gof_omit='NULL'
```

or

```
gof_map='all'
```

None of them worked. What should I do to make the goodness-of-fit ,such as AIC, display when the shape is changed or is there other methods to pivot the table with goodness-of-fit reserved?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer inspiring by https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/620. This issue has not been fixed by the developer, so it can only be solved by *add_columns*. The method is as follows.

```
mod_custom <- lm(hp ~ mpg + drat, mtcars)
cols<-broom::glance(mod_custom)
modelsummary(mod_custom, 
             shape=model ~term + statistic,
             add_columns=cols,
             )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkRd.png)

Comment: You can also use `get_gof()` from `modelsummary` to extract GOF if you don't want to load `broom`.

Comment: This's indeed a simpler way, thanks!